# Material UI DatePicker Showing Wrong Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, date-fns

The displayed date in Material UI Pickers is 1 day behind the selected date:

I selected 25th, the value in formik is 25th but the value displayed on the form is 24th.

```
  "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
  "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
```

```
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, DatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { format, addDays } from 'date-fns';

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <FastField
       as={DatePicker}
       variant="inline"
       disableToolbar
       name="startTime"
       format="PPP"
       onChange={date => {
         console.log(format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
         setFieldValue('startTime', format(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
       }}
       value={values.startTime}
   />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it might be related to time zone differences. Look at the first example here: https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started#introduction The function is format(new Date(2014, 1, 11), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), but the result is  '02/11/2014'. Try playing with the api of this library(i recommend moment.js...)

Comment: What am i looking for in the first example, I don't see anything

Comment: I've updated my comment

Comment: I tried to do something like this to address timezone maybe:    `format(endOfDay(new Date(date)), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` but no change

Comment: https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/Time-Zones try looking here, i think you might find the solution. i belive it's timezone related.

Comment: Just make sure it's the correct version..i aint sure about the link i sent you

Comment: I had the same issue, moved to moment and solved the issue for me.
`import MomentUtils from '@date-io/moment';`
ref: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've faced the same problem

After all, I added a `parseISO` method on my date, you need to specify the timezone of the component.

```
// import parseISO
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns';
```

On value (property which is date)

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  format={'dd/MM/yyyy'}
  label="Date"
  value={parseISO(salesPage.dateAt)}
  onChange={handleDateAtOnChange}
/>
```

On change

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { convertToLocalTime } from 'date-fns-timezone';


export const DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

/**
 * Format a date to a string
 *
 * @param date
 */
export const formatDate = (date) => {
  if (!date) return new Date().toLocaleString();

  // Get the timezone from browser using native methods
  const timezone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  const dateTmp = Date.parse(date.toLocaleString());

  const localDate = convertToLocalTime(dateTmp, {
    timeZone: timezone,
  });

  return format(localDate, DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);
};

const handleDateAtOnChange = (event) => {
  formatDate(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: The parseISO package is what it was missing for me. Thanks for sharing this tip

Comment: What is DateFormatEnum?

Comment: The format of the date you want.

`
export enum DateFormatEnum {
  YearMonthDay = 'yyyy-MM-dd',
  DayMonthYearPtBr = 'dd/MM/yyyy',
}
`

Answer (score 6):

its because datepicker takes input date-time in UTC ISOformat
Solution  - Convert UTC to local to ISO format

because server only accepts ISO date-time so I converted UTC to local timezone and sent it to server in ISO format

declare this somewhere

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
    return newDate;   
}
```

and do this where you need local datetime in ISO format `convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date).toISOString()`

Comment: it works for me, but instead of `-` I used `+`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can make use of moment lib method .utcOffset() and get this functionality to work.
- Make sure that the state is controlled and if you are fetching the data, remember to use the same method to format it again

```js
const handleDateAtOnChange = (e) => {
const date = moment(e.target.value).utcOffset(0, false).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
setDate(date)
}
```

```
<DatePicker 
value={date} 
onChange={handleDateAtOnChange}
format="MM/dd/yyyy"
/>
```

Comment: Hey! I've been trying to make work the code but the `.utcOffset(0, false)` does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this easily with "string concatenation".

In the .component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput readonly [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of birth" formControlName="dob" (dateChange)="formatDate($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="handleError('dob', 'required')">Date of birth is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the .component.ts

```
/* format date */
formatDate(e: any) {
  var d = new Date(e.target.value)
  var convertDate = d.toISOString().substring(0, 10) + d.toISOString().substring(10,);
  this.actorForm.get('dob')?.setValue(convertDate, { onlyself: true });
}
```

See my answer to this case at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73215526/15280648