# How to set timezone in material-ui/DatePicker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, datetime, material-ui

I have an application built with **Reactjs(front-end)** and **MeteroJS(back-end)**, I am using material-ui as UI design library. Recently we have implemented a globalization functionality in app, While developing global clock functionalities We have faced an issue with `material-ui/DatePicker`. In a search form I tried to create a date picker with user-specified timezone using `material-ui/DatePicker` and moment-timezone packages, and I passed the input date like this:

`new Date(moment.tz("userTimeZone").endOf('day'))`

But the **datepicker** is automatically converting the date to system local time + specified timezone time. How can I set specified timezone time in my DatePicker?

Comment: try using ParseIO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60382084/material-ui-datepicker-showing-wrong-date/64805720#64805720

Comment: @sonali Thanks for the response, i have installed date-fns package and created a date object for date picker using parseISO function, like this ,  parseISO(moment.tz("userTimeZone").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")    but it doesn't still showing the date in my local system, not with the preferred timezone date

Comment: @sonali I have tried date-fns-tz , utcToZonedTime function,  i can successfully convert the local time to proffered zone time but when changing the date from date-picker the date automatically compute the selected date with proffered zone date and set to that computed date( i have a tz setting functionality on date onChange function too ), I think the cause of this issue is, the output of material UI date-picker is UTC and it converting to preferred zone time, u have any suggestion to fix this issue?