# DatePicker AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, datepicker, bootstrap-5

```
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Follow up Consultation</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"  
                    formControlName="consultationDate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    
                    </mat-form-field>
```

This is my code, I am working on an angular app related to medical. When I pick a date from the calendar icon, it picks the exact date. But when I click on proceed order button, the date I see is one day back whatever date I select.
How to solve this Issue

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are doing for implementing the datepicker looks alright.

Not getting the exact date/datetime is a common misconception when working with dates. The problem might be coming from the way you filter out the incoming date into your component/service.

This question has already been answered.
Hopefully you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66105308/8681915